# dc.js month chart uneven spacing between bars

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am creating a chart using dc.js and as you can see the spacing between the months are different. The most notable is between February and March because February only has 28 days. How do I have even spacing between the months?

```
           chart
                //dimensions
                .height(250)
                .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 25, left: 50})
                //x-axis
                .x(d3.time.scale().domain(domain))
                .round(d3.time.month.round)
                .xUnits(d3.time.months)
                .elasticX(true)
                .xAxisPadding(20)
                //left y-axis
                .yAxisLabel('Dollars')
                .elasticY(true)
                .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
                // right y-axis
                .rightYAxisLabel('Quantity')
                //composition
                .compose(composition)

                .brushOn(false)
                .xAxis().tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b %y'));
```

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to set the `gap`

```
  magnitudeChart.width(480) //you should also set the chart width too
    .height(150)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40})
    .dimension(magValue)
    .group(magValueGroupCount)
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .centerBar(true)    
    .gap(65) //set the gap
    .filter([3, 5])
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0.5, 7.5]))
    .elasticY(true)
    .xAxis().tickFormat();
```

[dc bar reference](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/08/add-bar-chart-in-dcjs.html)

Comment: It is a composite chart, so the gap is being set on the charts in .composition(). I will try that anyway

Comment: Unfortunately when I try to add a gap to a composite chart it throws an error. And I definitely already have gap on the sub chart.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can reproduce the problem in jsfiddle.